# Using the verb "to have" + present simple verb

Tags: tense, present-perfect

Working on the book: Raymond Murphy. "*English Grammar in Use - Fifth Edition*" (p. 248)

> You have just run one kilometre, but you are exhausted.
>
> You say: I feel like I’ve (just) run a marathon.

As the book previously explained, the *present perfect simple* is **have/has** + *past participle*, and I noticed the verb "run" used in the solution is in *present simple* tense.

Is there a typo in the book or perhaps there are other types of constructions **have/has** + *present simple*.

Comment: **Run** is not in the present simple here.  **Run** is also the past participle of *to run*.  I **run**, I **ran**, I **have run**.

Comment: You might want to check out: principal parts of irregular verbs versus principal parts of regular verbs. Here's a good place to start: https://www.thoughtco.com/principal-parts-of-irregular-verbs-a-to-g-1689681 You have to memorize them. And the verb to read is the same in writing but pronounced differently.

Comment: Thank you both. Also, good reference @Lambie. I've just read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no typo - "I have run" is correct, because "run" is the past participle of "run".

From [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/run):

> present participle *running* | past tense *ran* | past participle *run*

Note: in the case of a regular verb, such as "walk", it would be ungrammatical to say *"I have walk", but if someone said it, you couldn't assume that "walk" was present tense.  After all, in "I must walk" or "I must run", "walk" and "run" are bare infinitives, not present-tense forms.

Comment: Thank you. About your note...Could you give me more information ? Is it incorrect to say "I have walk" but it is correct "I have run" ?

Comment: @F.Zer: ‘run’ is an [irregular verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_and_irregular_verbs). You can't say **I have walk*, because ‘walk’ is regular; walk, walked, walked.... It's how English works. Sorry.

Comment: For verbs other than "be", the infinitive is identical to the simple present, except that the infinitive sometimes needs "to".  So if you see the word "walk" on its own, you can't tell whether it's simple present, a bare infinitive (i.e. an infinitive without *to*), or (indeed) an imperative or a subjunctive.  In "I must walk" or "I must run" or "I must be", the verb after "must" is a bare infinitive.  This means (among other things) that it doesn't add an "s" for the 3rd person singular - so we say "she must walk", never *"she must walks".  (I use the asterisk to mark unacceptable sentences.)

Comment: Thank you, both. Yes, I understand now. The present perfect simple would be: "I have walked".